# use particles.js in webpack by installing with npm

Tags: npm, webpack, particles.js

I installed particles.js with: `npm particles.js --save`

**Error**: bundle.js:54 GET http://localhost:8080/particles.json 404 (Not Found)

I have tried different paths but it doesn't seem to work.

In the file **app.js**:

```
import 'particles.js/particles';
const particlesJS = window.particlesJS;
particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.json', null);
```

**Folderstructure:**
- index.html
- src/js/app.js
- src/js/particles.json

Comment: or if anyone can give me a step by step guide of how to implement this would be great...  I installed the package, setup the div in html, the only thing is not working is to get it right in the app.js file

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import "particles.js";

particlesJS.load('container', 'particles.json', function () {
  console.log('loaded');
});
```